# Run code in AsyncTask stucking UI

Tags: java, android, json, user-interface, android-asynctask

I'm trying a copule of days to figure it out, without success,

**Target:** get use country by IP using asyncTask without stucking UI, and save it into string parm.

**Problem:** The UI doen't move until the asyncTask finish it job :/

**MainActivity ,onCreate method:**

```
 .......
 JSONObject jsonObject;
        try {
            jsonObject = new getJSONObjectFromURL(LoginActivity.this).execute("http://ip-api.com/json").get();
            if (jsonObject != null) {
                if (!jsonObject.getString("status").equals("success"))
                    throw new InterruptedException();
                Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: jsonObject.tostring:" + jsonObject.toString());
                countryLocation = jsonObject.getString("country");
                Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: countryByIP " + countryLocation);
            }
            if (!isNetworkAvailable()/* || countryLocation == null*/)
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enable data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //in button click redo all that code for no internet connection,.
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**asyncTask:**

```
public class getJSONObjectFromURL extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, JSONObject> {

private Context context;

public getJSONObjectFromURL(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(Object... params) {
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL((String) params[0]);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);

        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        urlConnection.connect();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String jsonString;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        br.close();
        jsonString = sb.toString();
        return new JSONObject(jsonString);
    } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
    //Update the String..
}
}
```

Everything works perfect, i get the Json, able to read the Country from it, but MainActivity waiting for the onPostExecute to continue.

Comment: `AsyncTask.get()` ... so what is you expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running your `AsyncTask` in a synchrounous state.

```
jsonObject = new getJSONObjectFromURL(LoginActivity.this).execute("http://ip-api.com/json").get();
```

By calling `get()` you are waiting until the `Task` has finished it's job. Do not use `get()` if you want to have a truly asynchronous process. You can use a callback to get notified.